# Cycles: Complex material looks different when applied to plane versus object; why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am testing a complex material I created to simulate lunar regolith (terrain). I tested the material using a simple, undivided plane. I then applied the material to an object imported as a Wavefront OBJ (which is what I want to use for the final render).

**Problem:** The material looks significantly different (smoother) when applied to the terrain object. I have never seen this before. How do I make the material look the way it does when applied to the plane?

I cannot see any difference between the plane and terrain object; neither the plane nor the object have any modifiers. Same material, different results. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.6, Cycles, Windows 11

[image]

[plane and object blend file](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/regolith_plane_and_object_terrain.blend)

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (only the plane and the object)

Comment: Hi @moonboots. Thank you for your response. I have added a link the file in the OP.

Comment: If moonboots is on the right track in his answer, you might also consider switching on the 'Experimental' checkbox of Cycles, and using [Adaptive Subdivision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/object_settings/adaptive_subdiv.html)

Comment: Also, the material uses UVs coordinates, so you can't expect the same result from one mesh to another as they don't have the same UVs. If your shader is a repeatable texture, consider either playing with the Mapping Node's scale input, or using the Generated texture coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is consistent with an object scale issue.

Try to apply the scale of your imported terrain object. `Ctrl` + `A` then choose *Scale*.

Often imported models come in with a scale that is too big or small by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your suggestions! Ctrl+A Scale on the terrain object made a huge improvement (I added a screenshot of the result). The object comes from a third-party app called Daylon Leveller, and then I Decimated it in Blender with a ratio of 0.1. I also included a snapshot of the regolith material I cobbled together (it has some proprietary nodes I can't share). Trying to combine texture map footprints with procedural regolith.

Answer (score 1):

One of your object is subdivided, the other is not, the *Displacement* node can only work on subdivided mesh. Also, you didn't share the images but there seems to be several problems here like nothing plugged into the *Height* input of a *Bump* node, or 2 *Displacement* nodes plugged into a *Mix* (not sure that it will work correctly, you need to plug the images into a *Color Mix*, then plug the *Color Mix* into the *Displacement* that is plugged into the *Output*).